# bug in the code below in terms of synthax, design?

Tags: c++

what are problems with the code below in terms of synthax, design? Thanks for your answers.
the idea is to create a class Element which content a list of sub-element, it should be able to add sub-element, and get the average of all elements. I used to think in Java but not C++. so I'd like to know how to implement such class in C++ in a appropriate way.

```
class Elements
{
private:
    int nbValues;
    int values[MAX];
    double coefs[MAX];
public: 
    Element(){}

    double getAverage()
    {
        double sum;
        for(int i =1; i<= MAX; i++)
        {
                sum = sum+values[i]*coefs[i];
        }
        return sum/nbValues;
    }
    void addElement(int value, double coef)
    {
        values[nbValues]=value;
        coefs[nbValues]=coef;
        ++nbValues; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Try asking on [codereview.se].

Comment: sum and nbValues are of type `int`, getAverage returned sum/nbValues, will be of type `int`, not `double`.

Comment: sorry. I didn't use the c++ editor. It is an exercise of coding that i've met. So I didn't pay attention to these low level errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the current form all the methods are private. You can make getAverage() and addElement() public by:

```
class Elements
{
    int nbValues;
    int values[MAX];
    double coefs[MAX];

    Element(){}

    public: // all the members & methods below will be public

    double getAverage()
    {
    int sum;
    for(int i =1; i<= MAX; i++)
    {
        sum = sum+values[i]*coefs[i];
    }
    return sum/nbValues;
    }
    void addElement(int value, double coef)
    {
        values[nbValues]=value;
    coefs[nbValues]=coef;
    ++nbValues; 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Typo in Constructor Element instead of Elements(){}

You can initialize nbvalues in constructor:

```
 Elements() : nbvalues(0) {}
```